# PErformance issues for imagick

Tags: php, performance, imagick

I user imagick to create thumbnails with corners.

Here are the interesting lines:

```
$background = 'white';
$image->cropThumbnailImage($width,$height);
$im = new Imagick(); 
$im->newImage($width, $height, $background); 
//$image->sharpenImage(50, 1); 
$image->roundCorners( $cornersSize, $cornersSize);
$im->compositeImage($image, Imagick::COMPOSITE_OVER, 0, 0); 
$im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
$im->flattenImages(); 
$image = $im;
```

It takes 10 seconds on a server to create it!

On a small laptop, it takes 1.5s (still slow).

How can we improve that?

Precisions:

I relaunch the code with only one image: 20148px x 1222px. 10 seconds on the laptop, 20s on the server.

The server:

The laptop:

- php5-imagick : 3.0.0~rc1-1build1
- imagemagick : 7:6.6.2.6-1ubuntu1.1
- ubuntu 10.10
- 2048mo RAM 1333MHz DDR3
- Intel Core i3-370M 2,4GHz, 3MB

Server:

- Intel Xeon (16 Mo Cache)
- 8Go RAM (RDIMM)
- no website online.

Comment: It has nothing to do with the video card. You should include your PC/server hardware specification, and the size of the source image

Comment: what's the size of this image

Comment: we do it with different image, it is an average time. It takes some mo photos. (between 500ko and 6mo).

Comment: 500ko 6mo are **file** sizes. What is the image size? and can you be  **certain** please, when asking a question. WHat certain time took to resize a certain image? Thanks.

Comment: try to run that conversion from the command line. I suspect dramatical improvement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you can use your GPU to do some processing, it is not used in this case. Only your CPU.

It seems that you are doing some unnecessary steps. What is wrong with this:

```
$image->cropThumbnailImage($width,$height);
$image->roundCorners( $cornersSize, $cornersSize);
```

Comment: thanks for your quick answer. It doesn't make white corner. Do you have a solution to make white corners?

Comment: use $im->setBackgroundColor(new ImagickPixel('white')); before rounding corners

Answer (score 2):

If your server is Ubuntu 10.04/Debian 6, using Viruozzo, or maybe other virtualization platforms, or maybe just multiprocessor systems, this MAY be a bug with the OpenMP support of ImageMagick.

Imagemagick may be slow with imagick PHP extension on theese platforms. It takes seconds rather than miliseconds to make a simple image.

The solution that worked for me:
http://tellgren.com/blog/2011/03/24/trouble-with-imagemagick-on-vps/

Comment: the link you provided is dead, do you have an alternative ?

Comment: http://johannes.jarolim.com/blog/2011/11/21/extreme-slow-imagemagick-on-vps-with-ubuntu/

The problem is solved is later ubuntu and imagick versions:
#time convert  -resize 100x100 test.gif out.gif
real    0m0.742s
user    0m0.519s
sys     0m0.480s

OS Ubuntu 12.04.5 LTS
Plesk version 12.0.18 Update #38, last updated at Mar 12, 2015 03:55 AM

Version: ImageMagick 6.6.9-7 2014-03-06 Q16     http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2011 ImageMagick Studio LLC
Features: OpenMP